# How to change Object.prototype.toString?

Tags: javascript, class, prototype, tostring

I have a class:

```
class Test{
    contructor(){
       this.x = "test"
    }
} 

var t = new Test()

var toString = Object.prototype.toString
console.log(toString.call(t))
```

the log prints `[object Object]`, i would like it to print something like `[object Test]`, how can i do that? I tried doing

```
Test.prototype.toString = function() {
    return  "[object Test]"
}
```

but that didn't work, any help?

Comment: Why *would* that work? You're explicitly calling the `Object` version of `toString`.

Comment: In order to convert an object to a string you have the "JSON.stringify(obj)" function which does just that. 
Now Forgive me I may have not understood the question.

Comment: _"but that didn't work"_ - Then you messed something up -> https://jsbin.com/golobenata/edit?js,console

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm basically saving that as a variable and then calling the function for different objects, for example, if I have an array `a = [1,2,3,4]` and then I do `console.log(toString.call(a))` that prints `[object Array]`

Comment: @andreas meaning that if I do that and then do `t.toString()` that gives `[object Test]` but `toString.call(t)` gives `[object Object]`

Comment: Why do you want to know? I'm genuinely curious about this, as I don't see a good use for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Symbol.toStringTag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag) which has been introduced to exactly fulfill your needs:

```
class Test{
  contructor(){
      this.x = "test";
  }
  get [Symbol.toStringTag]() {
    // either return 'Test' or ...
    return this.constructor.name;
  }
} 

var t = new Test;

var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
console.log(toString.call(t));
```

However, if you use transpilers (Babel, TypeScript) and you target ES5 instead of ES2015+ (ES6+), and your target browsers don't support `Symbol.toStringTag`, you are in bad luck, 'cause unless you overwrite `Object.prototype.toString` to take into account classes, and yet your change is not granted to land before other 3rd parts scripts that might trap once the original `toString` so that it won't work, there's no way to provide, in a reliable way, such functionality with engines that are not compatible with `Symbol.toStringTag`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
class Test {
  contructor() {
    this.x = "test"
  }
  toString() {
    return "[object " + this.constructor.name + "]";
  }
}

var t = new Test();
console.log(t.toString());
```

Comment: The problem I found with this is that I would like it to work also with things like arrays and if I have an array `a` and do `a.toString()` I get the elements of the array, but would like `[object Array]`